# How do I read values from Azure app configuration

Tags: azure, go

I want my Go app to read values from [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview).

For my spring boot application I use

```
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-azure-appconfiguration-config</artifactId>
```

I was wondering if there is some similar, easy to use library for Go?

Comment: Requests for libraries or other third-party resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

As I see there is a method available to get the app [`configuration`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sdk-for-go-samples/blob/master/web/web.go)

```
func GetAppConfiguration(ctx context.Context, name string) (createdConfig web.SiteConfigResource, err error) {
    client, err := getWebAppsClient()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    createdConfig, err = client.GetConfiguration(ctx, config.GroupName(), name)
    return
}
```

Else, You need to define it as an environment variable, i.e in your [`webconfig`](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/running-go-applications-on-azure-app-service/) as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <!-- For Go webapp, we always generate azureapp.exe in wwwroot -->
        <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\site\wwwroot\azureapp.exe" startupTimeLimit="60">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```